# Android Studio and PNG vector images

Tags: android, vector

Creating vector images in Photoshop (for transparent backgrounds).  When I add them as the image source for my ImageButtons, and run the app, the image displays with a white background.

Can't find any useful info on why the images are not coming out transparent through the app.

Are there some additional steps/coding required to make vector images work properly?  I can't see why.

Example code, as requested:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btnGameUp"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:src="@drawable/arrowright"
    android:adjustViewBounds="false"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:cropToPadding="false"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_marginLeft="270dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="260dp" />
```

Comment: Can you add some code where you are adding the images

Comment: Just adding it as an image source, like any normal image.   See edit above. "arrowright" in the example is a vector.  It is a .png file that opens in photoshop as a regular vector image.

Comment: May be you are not exporting the images correctly. can you upload your `arrowright.png` file? does it have transparent pixels ?

Comment: Have you tried double clicking on the png in android studio to see if it has a background in the preview?

Comment: @dmsherazi - Link to the file here:  http://www.filedropper.com/arrowvector    it has transparent pixels, yes.

Comment: @Andy - I opened it in Android Studio as you suggested and can confirm it loads as a vector (background has a checkered square appearance).

Comment: Still no solution.   Bump?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No one came to help us, but we managed to find the solution on our own after hours of crying and holding each other for comfort.

In the layout xml file, you need to add the following line to each vector object:

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

That's it!  Tested and working perfectly.  Hope this helps someone.